# Do Kafka Broker Metrics Count Compressed or Uncompressed Data?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

If a Kafka producer uses snappy compression then do broker metrics like,

- BrokerTopicMetrics.topic.{topic}.BytesInPerSec
- BrokerTopicMetrics.topic.{topic}.BytesOutPerSec

represent the compressed or uncompressed bytes?

Answer (score 1):

These metrics represent compressed data. You can see that by changing the [compression.type](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_compression.type) in the configuration (on the producer or broker level).

The data is compressed by the producer so what is monitored coming into the topic are compressed bytes.